# Get a list from R string that contains a csv

Tags: r, csv

for one of my projects I will need to import the dataset (csv-File) outside of R and then assign it from the Ruby side of the project in R (this will be done with `rinruby` and already works).

In my R-Script I now need to create a list out of that csv file.

The variable contains an escaped string that contains the original csv.

```
data <- "\"\",\"futime\",\"fustat\",\"age\",\"resid.ds\",\"rx\",\"ecog.ps\"\n\"1\",59,1,72.3315,2,1,1\n\"2\",115,1,74.4932,2,1,1\n\"3\",156,1,66.4658,2,1,2\n\"4\",421,0,53.3644,2,2,1\n\"5\",431,1,50.3397,2,1,1\n\"6\",448,0,56.4301,1,1,2\n\"7\",464,1,56.937,2,2,2\n\"8\",475,1,59.8548,2,2,2\n\"9\",477,0,64.1753,2,1,1\n\"10\",563,1,55.1781,1,2,2\n\"11\",638,1,56.7562,1,1,2\n\"12\",744,0,50.1096,1,2,1\n\"13\",769,0,59.6301,2,2,2\n\"14\",770,0,57.0521,2,2,1\n\"15\",803,0,39.2712,1,1,1\n\"16\",855,0,43.1233,1,1,2\n\"17\",1040,0,38.8932,2,1,2\n\"18\",1106,0,44.6,1,1,1\n\"19\",1129,0,53.9068,1,2,1\n\"20\",1206,0,44.2055,2,2,1\n\"21\",1227,0,59.589,1,2,2\n\"22\",268,1,74.5041,2,1,2\n\"23\",329,1,43.137,2,1,1\n\"24\",353,1,63.2192,1,2,2\n\"25\",365,1,64.4247,2,2,1\n\"26\",377,0,58.3096,1,2,1"
```

And I would like to convert this to a R-List.

So my approach is basically to call `read.csv(data_as_string)` but unfortunately the signature is `read.csv(file_where_data_lies)`.

How can this be done?

Thanks so much!

Comment: See `text` argument in `?read.csv`

Comment: In general you can use `textConnection`, i.e. `myfunc(file = textConnection(data))`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Therkel mentioned above, `myfunc(file = textConnection(data))` did exactly what I was about to do. Thanks!